# .net MVC scaffold template: Check if model contains property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, t4

I am trying to modify the template that scaffolds a controller, to check if the model contains some property, and if so, write the c# code to assign it some value. so in my template, in the part that writes the Create actionresult (post):

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
<# if (UseAsync) { #>
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(<#= bindAttribute #><#= ModelTypeName #> <#= ModelVariable #>)
<# } else { #>
        public ActionResult Create(<#= bindAttribute #><#= ModelTypeName #> <#= ModelVariable #>)
<# } #>
        {



    <#
    if (THE MODEL CONTAINS A PROPERTY NAMED "creation_date")) { 
    #>
        <#= modelVariable #>.creation_date = DateTime.Now;
    <# } #>
```

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found answer myself, not sure it its the best solution but its working nicely:

```
<#
bool entityWithCreationDate = false;
foreach (PropertyMetadata property in ModelMetadata.Properties) {
    if(property.PropertyName == "creation_date") { entityWithCreationDate=true; break; }
}
if(entityWithCreationDate==true) {
#>
        <#= ModelVariable #>.creation_date = DateTime.Now;      
<#
}
#>
```

Comment: You could simplify it a bit by using LINQ `if (ModelMetadata.Properties.Any(c=>c.PropertyName=="creation_date")) {...} ` Note that you may have to add assembly directives/imports if your t4 doesn't already include them to support LINQ